# Uninstall link on extension page not working after upgrading from civicrm 4.7 to 5.9

Tags: extension

We have a Drupal 7 website which is migrated from another drupal 7 site to make a copy of it. On the new site CiviCRM was updated from civicrm 4.7.17 to civicrm 5.9.1. There are some civicrm extensions installed on the site. Those were hacked. So we want to uninstall those & add new code & again install it. But when I go to click the uninstall link on any extension it does not work through UI.

- How should I uninstall them manually & run db update in civicrm ?
- I also tried creating a new empty extension directory & changed the path of civicrm extension directory & resource url. But it gave missing extension message on extension page for each extension.
  So how to run the DB update in civicrm ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Adding to this it appears that there is possibly something more major ... not the extensions strictly

in other words we have lost functionality not just enabling / disabling on the extensions page, but through-out, for example :

-cannot see advanced search -cannot enable or uninstall extensions on page -cannot see configuration checklist

for each, it shows the header, nothing else

and in the profiles, cannot access advanced settings , it's just disappeared...

didn't find an exact match to anything related, but somewhat similar to wp menus issue here Why is my Menu and dashboards not working on clean installation on Wordpress?

First guesses :

flush the cache or settings files? (cleanup cache didn't initially do anything) check resource urls and directories are all correct... or change /check settings in the civicrm.settings.php file ?

H

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not work through UI" - do you see any error? or it completes the process but does not uninstall the ext? If the uninstall link is not clickable - do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: When I go to administrator > extension page & click on any uninstall link beside any extension it goes to siteurl/civicrm/admin/extensions?action=delete&id=extensionid&key=extensionkey but shows empty page instead of confirming the uninstall process like cancel or uninstall.
I don't see any error in the console.

Comment: is it possible the extensions code are not on the new site, eg are they in a directory, eg sites/default/civicrm/ext which you did not copy over to your new drupal instance?

Comment: Extension code is already on the new site in the proper directory.

Comment: Since you are describing a site that was migrated it would be worthwhile going through all the steps and double check civicrm.settings.php, Directories, Resource URLs etc as I suspect something is mistyped somewhere